# Cannot use external display's Desktop

Tags: macos, finder, display

**Edit: This is a bug**
After a restart, normal behavior returned.
Also, I noticed some files that appeared on the external display momentarily and disappeared. These files only showed from a Finder window showing the Desktop but did not show on either Desktop (aside from showing for a second when switching Desktops).

---

When using an external display (not mirroring), I cannot focus on the Desktop (by clicking on it) or drag files to it.
If I have an App open there, clicking anywhere on the screen will simply keep the focus on the latest App and will not switch to the Finder.
Dragging a file to the external Desktop simply bounce back.

Cannot say if it's a High-Sierra thing or earlier, or whether it's an expected behavior.

(Similar unanswered issues:
[Display desktop icon in all displays](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/303896/display-desktop-icon-in-all-displays)
[Can new files created in ~/Desktop be made to appear on a monitor other than the Main Display?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254439/can-new-files-created-in-desktop-be-made-to-appear-on-a-monitor-other-than-the))